# httping como usuario logueado

Tags: php, rendimiento

Estoy haciendo test de rendimiento a una web que estoy haciendo y para eso uso httping http://localhost/index.php

lo que me gustaría es poder hacer eso pero a una sección para la cual se requiere estar logueado y la verdad es que solo se me ocurre sacar la id de sesión y usar el httping a muestras?session_id=la id de sesión.

Se os ocurre algo que me permita hacer una prueba así¿?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Te refieres al comando [httping](http://linux.die.net/man/1/httping)? una opción sería usar [Autenticación de Acceso Básica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autenticaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso_b%C3%A1sica), que con httping sería algo así:

```
httping -g http://localhost/index.php -A -U usuario -P contraseña
```

Aunque de todas formas desde tu website en PHP tendrías que leer las credenciales y loguear al usuario (i.e. iniciarle una sesión).

NOTA: En este momento no puedo probarlo, pero debería funcionar de acuerdo a la información del manual del httping.

Comment: gracias @Roimer, creo que esto puede serme de mucha ayuda!